# documentation of coin-or clp linear programming package

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I am trying to use/test the `R` package `clpAPI` which calls the coin-or clp package. I find it hard to obtain the documents after keeping googling for a whole afternoon. When using it I found weird bugs but cannot explain why. Before I raise the bug I think it's better to ask for the document as a general request first. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home page of the CLP wiki is [here](https://projects.coin-or.org/Clp).

On this page you can find a link to the [CLP user guide](http://www.coin-or.org/Clp/userguide/index.html). The online API documentation does not seem to be generally accessible, but if you download the CLP source code and have [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) installed you can build the API documentation yourself.